# How to store id Command to JSON file in Linux with bash

Tags: json, linux, bash

I have the `id` `command` and I want to `store` the output of the `id` `command` in the `JSON` file like

```
{
id : uid=0(root) gid=0(root)
}
```

How to do that

Comment: That's not JSON format. What do you really want the result to be?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Barmar I just want my result in `JSON` form. the given format can be wrong but I want to store it in `JSON` form

Comment: show what you have tried. Do not expect ready answers... Show the expected output..

Comment: I tried commands like {"id": id } > file.json  as I am newbie to bash so I don't know much

Comment: Use the `jq` utility to format JSON properly.

Comment: JSON requires quotes around object keys and string values. JSON would be `{"id": "uid=0(root) gid=0(root)"}`

Answer (score 2):

Use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) to generate JSON

```sh
jq --arg id "$(id)" --null-input '$ARGS.named' > file.json
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be the simplest answer:

```
echo "{ \"id\": \"$(id)\" }" > file.json
```

But your question does not offer any specific info..so I am just guessing how you are trying t pull the info, how or where you need it...etc.